# How can be the overlapping error bars removed from line plots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make two line plots using ggplot2 of two different temperatures and two different genotypes. I am getting the error bars but I don't want them.

[image]

The error bars are overlapping with each other.
I am using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Faith_phylogenetic_diversity, aes (x=Temperature, y=faith_pd, color =Genotype))+
labs (x= "Temperature", y="Faith_pd")+
geom_line() +
geom_point(position="jitter")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(18,29))
```

How can I remove the error bars?

Comment: I can't say for certain without seeing the data in `Faith_phylogenetic_diversity` (using `dput()`) but I think it's an issue of the `geom_line()` not being able to tell apart data across genotype for each Temperature. So the end result is that it's actually zig zagging its way across the chart, making it look like error bars.